# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, maven, jpa

I am beginner in handling JPA with maven and JBOSS, with Restful to make my application I have the following problem arose me doing DEPLOY

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.company.test_resources_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
     Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: database.Photo column: fid_module (should be mapped with insert = \ "false \" update = \ "false \") "}}
```

Not that step, check all posles solutions, but did not find anything, can someone help me??

Thanks in advance

Below I show the SQL code in postgres that I have and I did the mapping.

I have three tables (**activity**, **event** and **photo**) where one of them (**photo**) refers to the other two (**activity** and **event**) but in a single column (**photo.fid_module**)

SQL Code (enginer database-->Postgresql):

```sql
CREATE TABLE activity (
  id_activity integer not null,
  name character varying(150),
  description text,
  CONSTRAINT id_activity_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_activity)
)

CREATE TABLE event (
  id_event integer not null,
  name character varying(150),
  description text,
  date timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT id_event_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_event)
)

CREATE TABLE photo(
  id_photo integer not null,
  path character varying(150),
  fid_module integer not null,
  CONSTRAINT id_photo_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_photo),
  CONSTRAINT fk_photo_activity FOREIGN KEY (fid_module)
      REFERENCE activity (id_activity) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_photo_event FOREIGN KEY (fid_module)
      REFERENCE event (id_event) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Now the mapping I did with the help of Netbenas and gave me the following code (I did the mapping for the three tables, but in presenting me the problem is in the class **Photo.java**).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "photo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "photo.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Photo p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "photo.findByFidPhoto", query = "SELECT p FROM Photo p WHERE p.fidphoto = :fidphoto"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "photo.findByIdPhoto", query = "SELECT p FROM Photo p WHERE p.idphoto = :idphoto")})
public class Photo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_photo")
    private Integer idPhoto;
    @Column(name = "path")
    private Recurso fidPath;
    @JoinColumn(name = "fid_module", referencedColumnName = "id_activity")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SliderWebHome fidModule;
    @JoinColumn(name = "fid_module", referencedColumnName = "id_event")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Publicacion fidModule1;

    public ModuloRecurso() {
    }
    .......
}
```

I am using JPA for persistence (but do mvn clean install and **mvn jboss-as: deploy** several pulls me hibernate dependencies) could anyone tell me what is my mistake or could solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in another answer, your Java code specifies the same join-column name for two fields, which can't work.

If this Java code is generated by a netbeans mapping tool, as it seems from your note

> Now the mapping I did with the help of Netbenas and gave me the following code ...

the bad Java mapping is probably caused by a bad combination of constraints in your SQL.

You have in your definition of the `photo` table:

```
  CONSTRAINT fk_photo_activity FOREIGN KEY (fid_module)
      REFERENCE activity (id_activity) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_photo_event FOREIGN KEY (fid_module)
      REFERENCE event (id_event) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

which attempts to make the column `fid_module` a foreign key referencing `activity` and also a foreign key referencing `event`, which can't work.

If you need foreign keys from `photo` to both of those tables, you'll need to use two different columns.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. then I'll have that remake my database estructure?? Tnank..

Comment: Yes.  I don't think you can have a single column be a foreign key to two different tables.

Answer (score 13):

You have two column mapped with the same name

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "fid_module", referencedColumnName = "id_activity")
 @JoinColumn(name = "fid_module", referencedColumnName = "id_event")
```

Change one of the name attribute!

Looking in your exception, you can read:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity
```

Comment: +1:  I think he's generating this Java, and the root problem is in the DDL, but this is definitely correct.

Comment: You have reason the name attibutes are the same , but The problem is that I need that the column of photo of this referenced with the tables: event and activity, how could I do that in the mapping?

Comment: I don't understand the answer, the mapping points to two different tables, or not? Why can you not have in both of those tables the same column name?

Comment: Yeah, but why can't I have same column with two different entities? Can anyone suggest solution to this please?